# Copy text in byobu when the mouse is "off"

Tags: tmux, mouse, clipboard, byobu

I recently started using `byobu` with `tmux` as a backend. I have learned that <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>F12</kbd> toggles "mouse mode" off and on. When "mouse mode" is on, I can select text with my mouse and paste it with the middle button as I would normally do. However, I cannot use my wheel to scroll up the pane's buffer.

If I turn the "mouse mode" off, I can scroll up normally with the wheel, but can no longer use the mouse to select. Since I often want to scroll up and copy text, this is a problem. The <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>PgUp</kbd> shortcut which works in regular shells is captured by my terminal emulator instead of `byobu` so that doesn't help me scroll back either.

The only workaround I've found is to enter scrollback mode with <kbd>F</kbd>. This lets me use <kbd>Up</kbd>,<kbd>Down</kbd> and <kbd>PgUp</kbd>,<kbd>PgDn</kbd> to scroll and I can indeed use the mouse to select, but I would still rather use the scroll wheel for this instead.

So, how can I use the mouse both to scroll up to see previous lines *and* for copying them?

Answer (score 0):

I have to admit that on my rii mini keyboard the only way to paste from byobu's memory was by holding <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> then pressing <kbd>a</kbd> and releasing. Afterward immediately hitting <kbd>]</kbd>. This pastes from byobu's clipboard that I enter either through <kbd>F7</kbd> or <kbd>Alt</kbd> plus <kbd>PgUp</kbd>. Selecting is by hitting <kbd>Spacebar</kbd> and moving cursor. Afterwards hitting <kbd>Enter</kbd> to copy.